# Пароль меняется сам по себе

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js

При обновлении данных пользователя (не меняю пароль) с фронта на бэк уходит старый правильный пароль, и вроде бы у пользователя обновляются только измененные данные. Но потом замечаю что у этого пользователя был изменен пароль. и это происходит когда данные пользователя обнавляются. С фронта данные уходят правильно, это проверила. Возможно ли что на стороне бэка генерируется и сохраняется другой пароль?

Comment: А как Вы получаете старый пароль? Он же должен хешироваться, и вы его никак не можете пользователю в форму вывести. Если это так, то само собой Вы пытаетесь записать хеш за пароль, который снова ещё раз хешируется, изменяя основной пароль.

Comment: Мне на фронт приходит уже хэшированный пароль. Значит при обновлении уже хэшированный пароль опять хэшируется и поэтому происходит данная ошибка. В этом случае, правильно будет вообще убрать поле пароли при обновлении и сделать отдельную модалку для изменения пароля? или есть какой-то другой способ не менять пароль пир обновлении данных?

Comment: Или модалку, или выводить пустое поле в форме и изменять пароль только в том случае, если это поле заполнено. Как Вы реализуете по UX - это уже не столь важно. Главное получить сам новый пароль и не перезаписывать его, если нового пароля нет.

Comment: Благодарю! Помогли!